# How to view old desktop notifications?

Tags: 20.04, security, notification

I understand from [this article](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-make-sure-your-disappearing-signal-messages-actu-1825921690) that on mac, chat apps like signal store your messages unencrypted in a notification queue.

I'm curious whether this is also true on Ubuntu 20.04 with GNOME.  What's the name of the file that houses old desktop notifications like this on ubuntu, and how can it be accessed?  Is it a sqlite db?

Comment: You'll have to provide release details, and then desktop if you're not using a default desktop.  My own desktop has a setting on how many notifications are stored; but I can also *clear* them and more meaning they're gone & the list returns to empty. You can also replace the *default* notification stack for some DEs too.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated this.

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news but, there isn’t a file … [NotifyOSD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD) doesn’t log those messages anywhere by default(what’s gone is gone) … you can, however, search this site and you will find ways to enable logging future messages if you want.

Comment: As a matter of security, deleting the messages is /good/ news, I just don't believe Ubuntu is doing that without canonical evidence, so I have this question.  Inotify logs a bunch of stuff, and surely other processes do, too.  Where?